# Git producing .bak and .orig files when merging

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to merge my UAT1 branch into MASTER branch and when I resolved all the conflicts, the files that were generated had .bak and .orig extensions. I looked at questions on here that refer to .orig file and learned that it's okay to remove them, however, what files do I commit? If I remove all the .bak and .orig files then there will be no files to commit hence all the files I merged will be gone.

I use winmerge as my mergetool.

[My git status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llJvs.png)

Comment: Don't ever post screenshots of text. Post the text itself, and use code formatting to make it look reasonable.

Comment: They will not be gone, they will already have been merged.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Will do! And I would love to have a conversation with you about your position an Instrument Engineer if you don't mind.

Comment: Hmm but i don't see them under my add staged files ?

Comment: WinMerge generates ".bak" files, not sure about the .orig ones. There is a setting in winmerge to disable it

Comment: @DaveShaw .orig is an artifact of git merge

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Files with `.bak` or `.orig` extensions shouldn’t be committed in version control.

To ignore the `.bak` and `.orig` files during merge, you can use below steps:

1. Add `*.bak` and `*.orig` in `.gitignore`.
2. Change mergetool.keepBackup option for git config as false

   ```
   git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
   ```

Now if you execute `git status` during merging, there will only show the changes for the files which states are **changes to be committed** and **changes not staged for commit**.

- If you only want to merge the `.java` file (changes to be committed state) into `master` branch, you can execute **`git commit`** to finish the merge.
- If you want to merge all the files as `.java` (changes to be committed state),  `.gitignore` and `xx.xx.xx.xx.component` (changes not staged for commit state) into `master` branch, you can execute **`git commit -a`** to finish the merge.

Comment: Ty! I will upvote as soon as I get my 15 reputation points as it is not allowing me to until I get the 15 reps